# Data(longitude&latitude) extracted from .csv file and making a visual map with the coordinates

Tags: python, google-maps, csv, dictionary

I have a .csv file where it has all the airports and other info

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list) 

with open('airports.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f) 
    for row in reader: 
        for (k,v) in row.items(): 
            columns[k].append(v) 

print(columns['longitude_deg'])

print(columns['latitude_deg'])
```

this outputs something like

```
['-74.9336013793945', '-151.695999146', '-86.7703018188477', '-91.2548980712891', '-112.165000915527', '-116.888000488', '-104.34400177002', '-82.2190017700195', ......]
['-74.9336013793945', '-151.695999146', '-86.7703018188477', '-91.2548980712891', '-112.165000915527', '-116.888000488', '-104.34400177002', '-82.2190017700195', ......]
```

for both longitude and latitude.

how can i use these to pinpoint the locations on a map?(with python)

Comment: Any luck with my provided answer? Any additions to your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it on google-maps (as your tag indicates) you will need to use a Python wrapper for the Google Maps javascript API. You will need to use something like http://code.google.com/p/pygmaps/.

Install it with:

```
pip install pygmaps
```

Then for example:

```
import pygmaps

mymap = pygmaps.maps(39.0194, 125.7381,8)
mymap.addpoint(39.0194, 125.7381)
mymap.addpoint(37.5665, 126.978)
mymap.draw('./mymap.html')
```

Will produce:

[image]